# Java Method.getName() not matching to string

Tags: java, methods, matching

I've tested this on several different methods. The string I compare `s` to is exactly the same as the one that shows up in the log file. The apostrophes are to make sure there's no spaces. Anyone know what's going on?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.util.Log;

public class Button {
    public Button () {
        for(Method m1:MyOtherClass.class.getMethods()) {
        String s = m1.getName();
            if(s == "Update") {
                Log.i("result","true");
            }
            Log.i("test", "'" + s + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in:

```
if(s == "Update")
```

Replace it with

```
if (s.equals("Update"))
```

== compares references when dealing with Objects (like String), not content/value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare Strings (or any Objects) by `==`. Use `s.equals("Update")`

`==` is used to check if references contains same Objects, not if Objects contains same values,

for example

```
Integer i1=new Integer(1);
Integer i2=new Integer(1);
Integer i3=i1;
//checking references
System.out.println(i1==i2);//false
System.out.println(i1==i3);//true

//checking values
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2));//true
System.out.println(i1.equals(i3));//true
```

Comment: Don't worry. Everyone is comparing Strings this way at first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use equals() method from `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`"Update".equals(s)`
This does proper value comparison.